# How to know the loading status of XML file in HTML Agility Pack in C#...?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xml-parsing, html-agility-pack

I am using HTML Agility Pack in  C# to Scrape email, article title, name data from XML. I am able to scrape data **successfully for smaller files (size around 100 MB).** but it **fails to extract when the file size is bigger (500 MB)**

I could not figure out where i am doing wrong.

**1. How can i know if the file is loaded or not before parsing.**

**2. Know the status of parsing.**

**Here is the code i used...**

```
     HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument someDoc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        someDoc.Load(@"C:\Users\Raj\Desktop\pmc_result.xml");
        HtmlNodeCollection articles = someDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//article/front/article-meta");
        foreach (var node in articles)
        {
            string email, name, title;
            try
            {
                email = "";
                name = "";
                title = "";
                try
                {
                    email = node.SelectSingleNode("./contrib-group/contrib/address/email").InnerText;
                    title = node.SelectSingleNode("./title-group/article-title").InnerText;
                    name = node.SelectSingleNode("./contrib-group/contrib/name/surname").InnerText + " " + 
                        node.SelectSingleNode("./contrib-group/contrib/name/given-names").InnerText ;

                    listView1.Items.Add(email);
                    listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(name);
                    listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].SubItems.Add(title);
                }
                catch (Exception ex) { }
               // textBox1.Text += node.SelectSingleNode("./surname").InnerText + Environment.NewLine ;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { }

        }
```

Someone Please Help me.

Comment: What does "it fails to extract" really mean? Are you getting any exceptions? Are you getting wrong results?

Comment: Exception `System.OutOfMemoryException: 'Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.'` @ someDoc.Load(@"C:\Users\Raj\Desktop\pmc.xml");

Comment: However,it worked with XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xDoc.Load(@"C:\Users\Raj\Desktop\pmc.xml"); But still i wonder why there is memory failure with HAP. Thanks for response.

Comment: If you your application does not have enough memory allocated it will logically fail when you try to load more things into memory. I suggest you search on the inter webs how to increase the available memory or how to investigate potential memory leaks.